# Magento2 admin order history editor issue

Tags: magento2, tinymce, editor, order-history

I have added tinyMCE editor in Order status history for comment field, the issue is when i get ajax response, editor disappears instead its showing normal textarea field, please find below screenshots of tinyMce editor field and ajax response field respectively:

[image: order history on landing page]

[image: order history while ajax comment]

I have used below code in this page to use tinyMCE editor:

```
<textarea name="history[comment]"  id="history_comment" class="textarea" cols="80" rows="20"></textarea>
                <script>
                 require([
                    'jquery',
                    'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
                ], function(jQuery){

                var config = {}, 
                    editor;

                jQuery.extend(config, {
                    settings: {
                        theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,' +
                                                    'fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code',
                        theme_advanced_buttons2: null,
                        theme_advanced_buttons3: null,
                        theme_advanced_buttons4: null
                    }
                });
                editor = new tinyMceWysiwygSetup(
                    'history_comment',
                    config
                );
                editor.turnOn();
                jQuery('#history_comment')
                    .addClass('wysiwyg-editor')
                    .data(
                        'wysiwygEditor',
                        editor
                    );
            }); 
                </script>
```

Comment: Please share your ajax code

Comment: Actually, this is default magento ajax request/response used for adding comment on order view page

Comment: Most probably your DOM is getting reset after the ajax call. Hope you have found the issue till now

Comment: @AshwaniShukla. Thanks for your reply.  Yes, you got it right that DOM is being reset after ajax call. I have tried so many solutions till date but nothing worked unfortunately. You may guide me if you know any proper solution.

Comment: try to bind the editor using jquery "on" ( http://api.jquery.com/on/ ). And I will be able to help you more if you could please let me know the purpose of ajax and it's code.

Comment: Actually we have used magento2 inbuilt tinyMCE editor script for comment textarea in order history section in Order view page in admin so in place of textarea, it will display like editor and its working fine at the first time reload but when we submit comment by clicking button it submits form with ajax(this is default behavior) but in response editor disappears instead it should be same tinyMCE editor there.

Comment: @bhargavshastri Its just time wasting I start debug it but it leads me to to much alterations in all area like the UI, reattachment of editor event after ajax call and after that you have to change the attribute save in db for html from string this is actually the major change save the content.